# systemd-shim error

Tags: upgrade, 16.10

I got a strange error after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10.

The Software Updater suggests me a Partial Update:

Could not install 'systemd-shim'

The upgrade will continue but the 'systemd-shim' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.

subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2

I saw this answer:

> I renamed
>   `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service`
>   to
>   `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak`
>   and did `sudo apt upgrade` again and after that no more systemd-shim
>   errors.

But I am unable to rename as in mouse right click 'rename" is disabled.

Comment: What is your question? The last sentence isn't a question.

Comment: you would need root permissions to rename the file (use `sudo mv`) but I am not sure this is a good idea or will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You should not install `systemd-shim` on a system which already has `systemd` as its PID 1.

Comment: I want to rename this file                                                                                           /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak