# Unable to purge or reinstall `systemd-shim` and `cgmanager` packages

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, systemd

### Introduction

I happened to install the package `systemd-shim` on my computer. However, it returned an error saying it could not be configured.

So for the time being I let it be just like that. However, whenever I want to perform any other operation using `apt`, it shows up in the list: `1 package not installed` and yet it does not get installed properly even with a `--reinstall` command.

### The problem

Then I decided that I'd simply remove it, using `apt purge`.
However, that does not work either. Here's a part of the error I get:

```
insserv: Starting .depend.start depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service .depend.start and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package cgmanager (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cgmanager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same is true regarding the package `cgmanager`, which was apparently also incompletely configured at the time of incomplete configuration of `systemd-shim`.

The same error occurs also when executing `sudo apt install --reinstall mdadm`, a step recommended by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/786444/539567):

```
insserv: Starting .depend.start depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service .depend.start and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting .depend.start depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried clearing the `apt` cache, i.e., the local directory where downloaded `.deb` packages are stored for them to be installed on the current/next run, but to no avail.

I am unable to find a solution anywhere specific to my situation, hence the question. Other questions ([A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849947/systemd-shim-error), [B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786356/broken-package-but-cannot-purge-or-reinstall-it)) involve issues that have arisen during 16.04-->16.10 upgrade. However, I am using 16.04 and do not intend to upgrade my system in the near future. I had manually tried to install the package(s) and encountered the above-mentioned errors.

My system works properly and doesn't encounter any *functional* errors due to this, but it is better to resolve it than just leave it lying there, so I would appreciate any help that you can offer.

### Update

I ran the command `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a` and here's more such output:

```
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1.bin for module i915_bpo
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mdadm
```

Comment: I know it's been long, but just in case someone's wondering, I've since got rid of my Ubuntu Unity installation and switched to Ubuntu Mate on 16.04 using gdm2 built off of the legacy GNOME desktop. It works very well given the issues I was having earlier. Perhaps because it has less graphics demands and I have an AMD GPU.